# AJAX sends file, but PHP wont receive it, if file is too large (but it is not)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I am using AJAX to upload two images (in base64 encoding). It works perfectly fine if the images are small (e.g. 500kB one image and 300kB the other, <1MB in total). However, if the images are larger (e.g. 1.5MB and 300kB), the larger image is not recieved by PHP (only the other one can be seen). That suggests that a limit could be reached on the server side, however the PHP parameters post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are set to 256MB, so should not be a problem.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Here is the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'upload.php',
    method:'POST',
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: {orig:original,image:cropped},
    success:function(data)
    {
        $modal.modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
echo print_r($_POST);
```

Here is the PHP setup:

```
file_uploads    On
max_execution_time  120
max_file_uploads    20
post_max_size   256M
upload_max_filesize 256M
```

Comment: In the developer console, are you seeing a server error message? It is possible that the server itself (Apache, Nginx, etc.) might have a limit, too. Nginx, for instance, defaults to 2MB usually, and 1.5MB base64 encoded is pretty close to that.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I do not see any error in the developer console. But I will try to check those limits with server admins. Thanks!

Comment: To debug this further, forget AJAX for now and just make a simple boring HTML form with a file upload, and try a large file. You should see a loud error message then.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried simple HTML upload - it works fine for large files (20MB+). I also tried to simplify the ajax code to upload only one image and tried different image sizes. It seems there is clear cutoff at 1MB of sent data (payload in console). If uploaded variable is more than 1MB, it is not recieved (but the rest is recieved).

Comment: I just tried that on different webhosting and it works fine there. So it seems it is indeed some server setting. Will work with the webhosting admins to resolve it.

Comment: Resolved. @ChrisHaas thank you so much for your guidance! You were right from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with webhosting admins we discovered that the issue was caused by nginx limit  `client_max_body_size`, which was set to 1MB.